# Loop through elements and set Gigya share title

Tags: jquery, gigya

I'm attempting to loop through a series of divs and retrieve a data attribute for use with the Gigya social sharing API. The Gigya API documentation is listed here: https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/postBookmark+Working+Example

I have successfully looped though my divs using jQuery .each and logged the result in the console, but I'm having trouble getting the value of the data attribute into the Gigya code. Right now it's getting the data attribute value of the last div item. Code follows. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-item" data-title="The First Post Title">
    <h2>The First Post Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-title="The Second Post Title">
    <h2>The Second Post Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-title="The Last Post Title">
    <h2>The Last Post Title</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".grid-item").each(function(){
$this = $(this);
var dataTitle = $this.data('title');
// console log each title
console.log(dataTitle);

// GIGYA CODE
// Define an image media item:
image = {
    type: 'image',
    src: 'https://demo.gigya.com/images/recipe3.png',
    href: 'https://demo.gigya.com/recipe3.php'
};
// Define a UserAction object specific for Twitter
uatw = new gigya.socialize.UserAction();
uatw.setLinkBack("https://demo.gigya.com/recipe3.php");

// attempt to set the title for Gigya. Currently outputting the last div's title :(
uatw.setTitle(dataTitle);

// Variable definition for Twitter share, note the Twitter specific UA object
TWParams = {
    provider: 'twitter',
    url: 'https://demo.gigya.com/recipe3.php',
    userAction: uatw,
    cid: 'Twitter Shares from Gigya postBookmark demo.'
};
});
```

Comment: in case this is supposed to *display* 3 pictures, each one with one different title. are you saying all of the pictures are ending up with the same (last) title?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Scaramouche

Comment: in that case, could you provide a fiddle with the relevant code and the gigya plugin in action?

Comment: Will do, hang tight.

Comment: Here you go @Scaramouche https://codepen.io/kennycrippen/pen/JLLdwr